# Discussion forum for each group

Tags: organic-groups, nodes

I need to set up a forum kind of discussion board for each group that is created. Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Panels and create a forum looking View (table) thats a copy of the same view that shows your Group content and then add it somewhere on the page. I wouldnt know how to add the 'forum' on a seperate page though.

You could add a select list in the group node form and have 'forum' or 'post' options.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [Og Forum D7](https://drupal.org/project/og_forum_d7) module?

This module allow to make some forum and their topics owned by an Organic group, just like any other group content.

This is simply done by adding a group audience field to the forum's taxonomy terms and topics and by automating some task (like selecting the same group audience for a topic than its parent forum)